# I couldn't get 2 NICs working together

Tags: 10.04, apache2, ethernet

I've got an Ubuntu 10.04 server with this configuration:

eth0: 192.168.10.XXX mask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.10.254
eth1: 192.168.0.XXX mask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.3

eth0 is used for incoming and outgoing trafic (internal webserver)
eth1 i want to use for accessing the network: 192.168.51.0/24 by gateway 192.168.0.1

when eth1 is down, the webserver is reachable.

When i want to bring the state of eth1 to up, i use the following commands:

```
$ sudo su
# ifconfig eth1 up
# route add -net 192.168.51.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1
# ping 192.168.51.XXX
[i've got contact]

# ip route add default via 192.168.10.254
# ping 192.168.51.XXX
[i've got contact]
```

but when i want to access the webserver, i can't get contact.

Can someone please give me some advice so the network .51 AND the webserver (network .10) is reachable?

### ifconfig

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr mymac  
          inet addr:192.168.10.2  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fee0:39c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:23207 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24924 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2683656 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:12841148 (12.8 MB)

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr mymac  
          inet addr:192.168.10.10  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr mymac  
          inet addr:192.168.0.237  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fee0:3a6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3742 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:143 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:318099 (318.0 KB)  TX bytes:12994 (12.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:3175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:221390 (221.3 KB)  TX bytes:221390 (221.3 KB)
```

### route -n

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.51.0    192.168.0.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.254  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.254  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

### /etc/network/interfaces

```
# cat /etc/network/interfaces 

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static 
address 192.168.10.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.10.254

# A second ip address for SSL
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.10.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.10.254

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.0.237
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.3
post-up route add -net 192.168.51.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to askubuntu - to mark an answer as solved, just click the tick button next to your answer.  Thanks.

Comment: then a nice orange box will show with the message: You can accept your own answer in 17 hours

Comment: hey - come back tommorrow! - well done on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I've got the solution!

The command i had executed was:

```
# route del -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 eth1
```

After that command my: 0 network, 10 network AND 51 network was accessible.
I also edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and uncomment `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` before, but i'm not sure if this is necessary.

my configs:

## ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:e0:03:9c  
          inet addr:192.168.10.2  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fee0:39c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:53794 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:53916 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6812117 (6.8 MB)  TX bytes:21573511 (21.5 MB)

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:e0:03:9c  
          inet addr:192.168.10.10  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:e0:03:a6  
          inet addr:192.168.0.237  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fee0:3a6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:29845 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:469 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2555869 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:42872 (42.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8157 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8157 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:624350 (624.3 KB)  TX bytes:624350 (624.3 KB)
```

## route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.51.0    192.168.0.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.254  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.254  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

## /etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static 
address 192.168.10.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.10.254

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.10.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.10.254

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.0.237
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
post-up route add -net 192.168.51.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post the results of the following commands:

```
$ifconfig
$route -n
```

Also post the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`. You may use this command for this:

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

UPDATE 1:
Okay, in `/etc/network/interfaces`, set gateway of eth0 to `192.168.0.1` and remove all other gateway entries. Reboot system and see if it works now.

And I presume that you've edited the default gateway in the router config too, as most routers are set with a default gateway of `192.168.1.1`. Do check the router gateway at once.

Comment: your comment results in no connection at all

when i put the gw 192.168.0.1 in eth1, no change at all.

Comment: What's the router gw: 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.10.1 or 192.168.1.1? Are you using two routers with the same gw addr? Check the router gw & netmask first; seems to be a case of mismatch.

Comment: i've got a complex network situation. i made a network diagram for you: http://i.img-share.net/CP5nlDubSW.bmp

Comment: Falco, as far as I'm aware, multiple NICs can be used on the same system provided that they're part of two `different` networks! The first router connects to both the sub-nets and that's the reason why it's not working the way it should. That's what I can say according to my experience.

Comment: so, (if i understand well) in these configuration it is impossible?

Comment: I studied the image again, but failed to understand which system you wish to connect here? The only one with 2 connections seems to be disconnected from the .51 sub-nw. I've used multiple NICs on same system, but with diff n/w. Check the switch routing tables; some tweak there should work.